# React Run Error Can't resolve react-dom/client

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I ran my old react project and got this error:

```
ReactDOM render no longer supported
```

Error:
https://bobbyhadz.com/images/blog/react-reacdom-render-no-longer-supported-in-react-18/reactdom-render-no-longer-supported-in-react-18.webp

I tried to use createroot and got this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in 'C:\Users\EditHamster\Documents\Projects\weather\src'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must upgrade your React & ReactDOM Version to latest to use createRoot

```
npm i react@latest react-dom@latest
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to install/update React and ReactDOM

```
npm i react react-dom
```

Or check for alias at webpack.config

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
    },
  },
```

If you have, remove this line

```
'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
```

Comment: I have same problem, but I have alias like this: 
`alias: {
      react: require.resolve('react'),
      'react-dom': require.resolve('react-dom'),
      'react-router-dom': require.resolve('react-router-dom'),
    }`

Removing these throws error `Can't resolve 'react-dom`, `Can't resolve 'react'`. How to fix this?